# Unit test for observable in angular 2+

Tags: angular, unit-testing, user-interface, karma-jasmine

How to write the unit test case of the function which returns an observable

```
public notificationStream(): Observable<Notification> {
return this.notificationSubject.asObservable();
```

}

Comment: subscribe this method in your spec file and compare the resoponse

Comment: how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

One approach can be like this

```
it('should check if notificationStream works correctly', () => {
   let mockResponse = { prepare your mock Response}
   this.component.notificationStream().subscribe(resoponse => {
     expect(response).toBe(mockResponse)
   })
   //call function from you component which contains following line 
   //this.notificationSubject.next(mockResponse);
  });
```

After subscription you will get all values in response that you pass to `.next()`